# How do I get my apps from device A to automatically install on device B when I sign in to my Google account?

Tags: applications, sync, google-account

I have heard that it is possible for apps to be automatically synced between Android devices so that when you sign in to another Android device with your Google account, your applications will automatically be redownloaded for you without you having to manually do so.

I have a Nexus S which I do reset often, but it has never redownloaded my applications when I sign in to my Google account. I have checked the box 'Backup data to Google servers' in the settings.

So how can I get my apps to be automatically downloaded when I sign in with my Google account?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Plus you wouldn't want it to be fully automated, for example I might want a different set of apps on my Android mobile phone vs my Android Parrot car radio (http://www.parrot.com/uk/products/hands-free-car-kits/parrot-asteroid) vs my Android tablet. I would like a solution where I can better manage the apps between devices online.

Comment: I have a Nexus S and it has always just worked for me.  It didn't auto download on my Galaxy Tab, but it always does on my phone.

Comment: @CaseyB That is curious. I expected it to also always work at least on the same device. But mine has never worked. On the online market place, I can see a list of my apps. But they do not download automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you go Menu -> Settings -> Privacy there are two options.  They are Back up my data and Auto restore.  Are they both checked?

Comment: Yep, both are checked!

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. I did a factory reset on my device, then logged in to my Google account and then installed my applications from the Android market on the device.

Then when I did another factory reset and logged in to my account again, my applications were restored.

Previously I installed applications through the Android market in the browser (market.android.com) and they got sent to my device. Maybe those ones cannot be restored? I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the correct options selected, though it can take awhile after you sign into the market. Try appbrain with fast the fast web installer companion app,its always been a great alternative access to the market.

It produces separate lists for each device you use and it looks like you can restore apps based on whatever list you select.

Alternatively, you can't go wrong with Titainium Backup if you are prepared to root your phone. Not much it can't do.